# What is the delta of an at-the-money European call option with respect to volatility?

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, greeks, european

> Question: What is the delta of an at-the-money European call option with respect to volatility?

Note that 
$$\frac{\partial\Delta}{\partial\sigma} = N'(d_1) \frac{\partial d_1}{\partial\sigma} = N'(d_1) \frac{- d_2}{\sigma} = \frac{-N'(d_1)d_2}{\sigma}$$
where $N(\cdot)$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution.
I am not able to deduce anything from this equation.

This [QFSE post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18059/effect-of-volatility-on-the-delta-of-a-call-option) states that higher volatility for in-the-money option will have lower delta whereas higher volatility for out-of-the-money options will have higher delta.

Based on this [website](https://theoptionprophet.com/blog/the-complete-guide-on-option-delta), it seems that higher volatility will lead to $\Delta = 0.5.$
But I am not able to show this.

Comment: The question is strangely asked. I would interpret it as “first-order sensitivity (delta) to volatility”, i.e. vega, not $\frac{\partial \Delta}{\partial \sigma}$.

Comment: As an aside: the "holy trinity" of strikes are d2=0, ATMF, d1=0, and the holy trinity of Greeks are Vega,Vanna, and Volga. Understand the behaviour of these three Greeks at those three strikes, and you understand 95% of the volatility smile.

Comment: How to obtain that ATMF implies $d_2=0$?

Comment: d_2 = 0 is not the ATMF strike. The answer by @siou0107 is the answer to your question.

Comment: But he doesn't answer when the call is ATMF.

Comment: When the call is ATMF, $d_2 = - \frac{1}{2} \sigma \sqrt{T} \sim 0$. If you want a real 0 sensitivity, in a BS framework, it is at the strike $K = Fe^{-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}T}$

Comment: How do we know that $-\frac{1}{2} \sigma \sqrt{T}$ is small? Can we always assumes that the product is small?

Comment: @Idonknow What does it matter whether $\sigma \sqrt{T}$ is small? Your question is what is the sensitivity of the delta with respect to volatility for an ATM(F) option. So then plug in the vlaue of $K = Se^{r(T-t)}$ in the expression for $\partial \Delta / \partial\sigma$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your computation, you can observe that the $N’$ term is always positive, between 0 and 0.4. As $\sigma$ is always positive, you can focus on the $-d_2$ term. When $d_2 > 0$, i.e. call is ITM, delta has a negative sensitivity to volatility ; conversely for OTM call. That is in line with your remark.

Comment: What about at-the-money?

Comment: At the money it is fairly insensitive, as $d_2 \approx 0$

Comment: How do you obtain that $d_2\approx 0$ for at-the-money option? I have $d_2 = \left( \frac{r}{\sigma} - \frac{\sigma}{2}\right) \sqrt{\tau}$ only.

Answer (score 1):

In the following, I am assuming the BS73 model and I assume that "ATM" means

$$
S = Xe^{-r\tau}
$$
The pricing formula for a European call then becomes
$$
\tag{1}
O\propto N\left(+\frac{1}{2}\sigma\sqrt{\tau}\right)-N\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sigma\sqrt{\tau}\right)
$$
times some scaling factor which is irrelevant for our purpose.
Clearly, 
$$
Vega\equiv\frac{\partial O}{\partial \sigma}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\tau} \cdot{} n\left(\frac{1}{2}\sigma\sqrt{\tau}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\tau} \cdot{} n\left(-\frac{1}{2}\sigma\sqrt{\tau}\right)
$$
Leading us to
$$
\tag{2}
\frac{\partial O}{\partial \sigma}=\sqrt{\tau}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(0.5\sigma\sqrt{\tau}\right)^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}
$$
Thus:

- For longer maturities, the Vega is larger than for smaller maturities
- For all practical purposes (i.e. $IV<75\%$, $\tau<1yr$, you can **approximate the ATM Vega** to 
  $$
  \tag{3*}
  Vega \approx \sqrt{\frac{\tau}{2\pi}}
  $$

Comment: I think you are answering different question.

Comment: I interpreted your question **" What is the delta of an at-the-money European call option with respect to volatility?"** as the first derivative (hence Delta) w.r.t. Volatility.

Comment: I think you are calculating Vega. But what I want is how delta changes if volatility changes?

Comment: Funny enough: The result is the same, scaled by a factor of 2.